# XTVFS filesystem in linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

I am working on a project for set top boxes and I need to mount a HDD partition formatted with xtvfs filesystem.

I have only received the following information regarding xtvfs:

> The partition formatted with xtvfs is basically a type 1 (FAT12) to be used with xtvfs

I searched the internet and found a program called Copy+ that can be used to copy xtvfs images form one HDD to another.

The set top I am working on uses linux and so I need to mount and read the partition on it. 
I have the following question:

1. I did not find any xtvfs named filesystem supported in the kernel. Can I be able to mount it using vfat?
2. If not, then how do I get to work such a filesystem in Linux.

Comment: This is proprietary filesystem invented by Sky+. They probably did not want you (or anybody else) to easily read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information on XTVFS is hard to find and support is not widespread - http://wiki.ph-mb.com/wiki/XTVFS is probably the best page I found. I could not find a linux driver for it. XTVFS is based on FAT32 and mounting that on Linux will get you part of the way - basically for everything but the video files. The video files have a separate Video FAT and video data section. I wrote some code to read files from an XTVFS image and will share it once it is tidied.

Comment: FYI: I did eventually share the code on [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xtvfs/) a few years ago.